# How do I fix my code and make it iterate through all the rows in my 2D array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, iteration

My code iterates through a matrix that is converted into a 2D array however when I attempt to change the values based on certain rules the code never reaches the last row. There is no error, the program just ends before reaching the final row. It might be that the array is going out of bounds when it gets the counts of neighboring cells, however I would assume an error message would come from that and I'm not sure why that wouldn't work, I assumed I had gotten the conditions in the if statements right, but maybe not.

The 2D arrays I have used to test my code look like this (I thought this would shorten the code and allow for a better understanding of how the 2D array is used and how it looks)

Row0:1000
Row1 :0111
Row2: 0010

as well as

Row0:1000
Row1 :0111
Row2: 0010
Row3: 0100
Row4: 0001

both would always stop before reaching the last row.

Below is my code, its a bit much but I think its necessary to diagnose the problem.

the getNeighbors function basically just looks at the row and column position and counts the amount of 1 surrounding it, each cell has at most 8 neighbors (cells on the edge of the world will have fewer).

```
int getNeighbors(int **Bacteria, int rows, int columns, int  row, int column) {

    int count = 0;


    if (row==0 && column==0) {

        if (Bacteria[row+1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (row==rows && column==columns) {

        if (Bacteria[row-1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (row==rows && column==0) {

        if (Bacteria[row-1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (row==0 && column==columns) {
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (row==0) {
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (row==rows) {
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else if (column==0) {
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;

    } else if (column==columns) {
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    } else {
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column+1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row+1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (Bacteria[row-1][column-1] == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }



}

void changeGeneration(int **Bacteria, int rows, int columns) {

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
            int count = getNeighbors(Bacteria, rows, columns, x, y);

            if (Bacteria[x][y] == 1 && count < 2) {
                Bacteria[x][y] = 0;
            } else if (Bacteria[x][y] == 1 && count > 3) {
                Bacteria[x][y] = 0;
            } else if (Bacteria[x][y] == 0 && count == 3) {
                Bacteria[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Sacrifice some memory to build a wall  of zeroes around the `Bacteria` array and you can eliminate most of the code.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just an FWI, that program could be implemented with about a tenth of the amount of code you've written (probably less). Try and think about ways to remove duplicate code.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is a much simpler way to express what you're trying to do:

```cpp
  int count = 0;
  for (int n_row = row - 1; n_row <= row + 1; ++n_row) {
    for (int n_col = col - 1; n_col <= col + 1; ++n_col) {
      if (n_row >= 0 && n_row < rows && n_col >= 0 && n_col < columns
          && (n_row != row || n_col != col)) {
        if (Bacteria[n_row][n_col] == 1) {
            ++count;
        }    
      } 
    }
  }
```

Second, when you say it doesn't reach the last row, what is the value of `rows` in your examples? Keep in mind that the total number of rows is one greater than the highest row index. So if you have rows 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, `rows` should be 5.

Comment: The value of rows and columns is the maximum rows and maximum columns in the array. Also if I use your code how do I change what I pass to the function?

Comment: @Unknownzdx If the maximum row index is 4 then the number of rows is 5

Comment: Yeah so rows is 5 and columns is 4

Comment: @Unknownzdx my best suggestion is to step through your code with a debugger (or if you don't know how to use a debugger, add some print statements to print out that values of variables at various points) to check that your understanding of the program is correct (like, what rows and cols are, and what values `getNeighbors` is being called with)